# Using foma/flookup from Windows command line

Tags: windows, parsing, command-line, nlp, morphological-analysis

I am following the foma tutorial on https://fomafst.github.io/morphtut.html, and everything has worked for me except *flookup*. I have added C:\Program Files\foma to my PATH system variable and compiled the lexc, foma, and bin files, but when I try

```
C:\Program Files\foma>echo "begging" | flookup english.bin
```

I get

```
"begging"       +?
```

And when I try

```
C:\Program Files\foma>echo "beg+V+PresPart" | flookup -i english.bin
```

I get

```
"beg+V+PresPart"        +?
```

The correct output should be

```
begging beg+V+PresPart
```

and

```
beg+V+PresPart  begging
```

respectively.

My best guess is that this is a compatibility issue between Linux and Windows. What should I do to make this work?

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, but in case someone still needs the answer: it's the trailing space after the word to analyze. This works in Windows 10 cmd:

```
$ echo city| flookup.exe english.bin
city    city+N+Sg
```

Note how the pipe has to come right after the end of the word, otherwise it will look up "city "